# Ember Data: Submitting only properties that are not null or empty

Tags: ember.js

I have defined a model with many different properties, but only a few of them are required when creating a record on my backend. Creating a new record with `createRecord` with only a few of the properties makes the rest of the properties to be null or "", which causes my backend to fail.

How can I make Ember create a model object with only the properties I'm passing to `createRecord` or, alternatively, how can I remove the null properties before they are sent to the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Saying you are using `RESTAdapter` and `RESTSerializer`.

```
//model.js (serializer)

serializeIntoHashForCreate: function(data, type, record, options) {
        let serialized = this.serialize(record, options);
        delete serialized.unwanted_prop;
        lodash.assignIn(data, serialized);
    }

//model.js (adapter)
createRecord(store, type, record) {
        var data = {};

        var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.modelName);

        serializer.serializeIntoHashForCreate(data, type, record, {includeId: false});

        return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.modelName), "POST", {data: data});
    }
```

Now you have customized adapter for `createRecord` method which is used by `store` to create a record for `model`